# Replace src of <img> by using its <div> classname

Tags: php, preg-replace

`$aaa ='<div class="myclass"><img src="imageurl"/></div>'`;

`$replace = $url`;

how to replace 'src' with $replace by using "myclass" ?

is that possible to do like this `"preg_replace('some pattern',$replace,$aaa)"`; ??

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$aaa ='<div class="myclass"><img src= '. $replace .' /></div>';
```

This is best way to do it. You dont need class name of parent element.

**Alternate Way**

If you are sure you want to do it by using classname of parent element try using JS

```
document.getElementByClassName('myclass')[0].children[0].src='er.jpg';
```

You can add  this JS code to the PHP file (in script tag) to achieve this.